# $e^{it}$ is not analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

Is the following reasoning correct?
$f(t)=e^{it}$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$, is not analytic because $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ so the complex derivative is not defined for an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. (Only for open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Yep that'll work if you mean complex analytic (i.e. holomorphic).

Comment: It's "analytic" if that means there's a power series that converges to $e^{it}$ for every $t\in\mathbb R.$ But if "analytic" means holomorphic, i.e. complex-differentiable on an open subset of the plane, then the restriction to $\mathbb R$ means it's not. I wonder if some might degine "analytic" for functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ to mean analytically continuable, in which case it would be analytic.

Comment: Maybe there's a confusion between an *analytic* function -- which allows a representation as a power series -- and the complex derivative, that means that the derivative of a function in $\mathbb C$-linear.  Hence our $f$ in question is analytic and has  a derivative, which is not complex.